# Scalar function throws error while using in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is:

*Write a query to display user name and password. Password should be generated by concatenating first two characters of user name , length of the user name and last three numbers in the phone number and give an alias name as USER_PASSWORD. Sort the results based on the user name in descending order.*

```
select
    name,
    concat(substring(name, 1, 2), cast(len(name) as varchar), cast(right(phno, 3) as varchar)) as USER_PASSWORD 
from 
    users
order by 
    name desc;
```

I get this error:

> cast(len(name) as varchar),
>
> - ERROR at line 5: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I believe concat() is limited to two arguments, so you would need multiple concats, or use `||`.

Comment: @Isolated No, you can use 3 parameters, works fine for me.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL-Server, Postgres?

Comment: @NorSer Not in oracle. (he has an Oracle error). Pretty sure oracle limits to 2.

Comment: @Isolated I see, missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have five issues:

1. `CONCAT` only takes two arguments so you either need `CONCAT(a, CONCAT(b, c))` or use the `||` string concatenation operator `a || b || c`
2. `CAST` requires the data type and length `CAST(a AS VARCHAR2(10))`
3. `SUBSTRING` is not an Oracle function, you want `SUBSTR`;
4. `LEN` is not an Oracle function, you want `LENGTH`;
5. `RIGHT` is not an Oracle function, your want `SUBSTR` with a negative index.

```sql
SELECT name,
       concat(
         substr(name, 1, 2),
         concat(
           cast(length(name) as varchar2(10)),
           cast(SUBSTR(phno, -3) as varchar2(10))
         )
       ) as USER_PASSWORD 
from   users
order by name desc;
```

However, you do not need to explicitly use `CAST` as you can use an implicit conversion between data types:

```sql
SELECT name,
       substr(name, 1, 2) || length(name) || SUBSTR(phno, -3) as USER_PASSWORD 
from   users
order by name desc;
```

---

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (name, phno) AS
  SELECT 'Benny', '0123111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Betty', '4567111' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Beryl', '2222111' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| NAME | USER_PASSWORD |
| --- | --- |
| Betty | Be5111 |
| Beryl | Be5111 |
| Benny | Be5111 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hywln9qu)

---

Which leads to the final point, don't generate obvious passwords; generate random or pseudo-random passwords. Then don't store them as plain text; instead store them as a salted-hash.

Answer (score 2):

Concat() is limited to two arguments in Oracle. Use `||` instead.

```
with my_data as (
  select 'abcdefg' as name, 12345 as phno from dual
  )
select
name,
  substr(name, 1, 2) || 
  length(name) ||  
  substr(to_char(phno),-3) as user_password
from my_data
```

```
| NAME    | USER_PASSWORD |
| --------|---------------|
| abcdefg | ab7345        |
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R0Df7jfc)